# How to use Active Directory based authentication in Power BI Service to query data as per user's entitlements from AWS Athena

Tags: authentication, powerbi, active-directory, amazon-athena, onpremises-gateway

I have a requirement that user need to connect Power BI cloud Service to Athena (via on-premises datagateway) and fetch the data according to the user persona setup in AWS.

[image]

I understood from MS documentation that I need to have the above setup. On-premises Power BI gateway needs to be installed in Windows EC2 instance to route the calls from PowerBI cloud service to Athena.

My questions are

1. How can Athena understand the end user who is querying the data from Power BI cloud Service?
2. On-premises Power BI gateway uses the hard-coded fixed service account to query the data from Athena (using Athena Connector + ODBC) and proxy the user(and caches the data in on-premises gateway), is there any way to pass the user information to Athena, so Athena can authorize and serve the data, according to user's persona (like not showing PII data for the unauthorized users)

Comment: was not able to resolve with Athena, had to use redshift and pass the user information to redshift to filter the data out